# Object copy versus clone in PHP

Tags: php, object, clone

Consider the following:

```
$object1 = new stdClass();
$object2 = $object1;
$object3 = clone $object1;

$object1->content = 'Ciao';

var_dump($object1);
 // Outputs object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["content"]=> string(4) "Ciao" }
var_dump($object2);
 // Outputs object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["content"]=> string(4) "Ciao" }
var_dump($object3);
 // Outputs object(stdClass)#2 (0) { }
```

Is it a normal PHP behavior that `$object2` has a content identical to `$object1` ?

To me it sound like `$object2` is a reference to `$object1` instead of a copy.
Cloning the object before changing the content does act like a copy.
This behavior is different than what happens with variables and seems unintuitive to me.

Comment: That's just another PHP-WTF resulting from missing specs.

Comment: See the example here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit why that is unintuitive for you?

Comment: It's unintuitive to me because the logic changes with the type of variable. As explained in following answers, it doesn't behave that way with arrays for instance.

Comment: In my opinion, it _is_ rather unintuitive in that as it stands, `$obj2 = $obj1` and `$obj2 =& $obj1` do the same thing.

Comment: @Antti29 - they don't do quite the same thing. `$obj2 = $obj1` results in 2 separate references to the same underlying object. So if you then do `$obj2 = $obj3`, your `$obj1` variable is unaffected. But if instead you start by doing `$obj2 =& $obj1` you end up with 2 variables sharing the _same reference_! If you then do `$obj2 = $obj3` you will find that `$obj1` now points to `$obj3` as well!

Answer (score 38):

Yes, that's normal. Objects are *always* "assigned" by reference in PHP5. To actually make a copy of an object, you need to `clone` it.

To be more correct though, let me quote [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php):

> As of PHP5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

Answer (score 14):

That's normal and I won't consider this unintuitive (for object instances):

```
$object1 = new stdClass();
```

Assigns a new object instance to `$object1`.

```
$object2 = $object1;
```

Assigns the object instance to `$object2`.

```
$object3 = clone $object1;
```

Assigns an new object instance cloned from an existing object instance to `$object3`.

If it would not be that way, each time you need to pass a concrete object instance, you would need to pass it by reference. That's burdensome at least but PHP did so in version 4 (compare [`zend.ze1_compatibility_mode` core](http://php.net/ini.core.php#ini.zend.ze1-compatibility-mode) ). That was not useful.

[Cloning allows the object to specify how it get's copied](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: @stereofrog: Well from an object oriented perspective, it's not. However, PHP *actually* makes a copy as well, a copy of the object identifier. The object value is only available by identifier since PHP 5, so actually, even with "I expect a copy" this is intuitive: You get the copy of the object identifier. The key point might be however to understand how OO is implemented in PHP.

Comment: @stereofrog: It would be much more confusing, when objects are going to clone itself every time its passed somewhere. You will also never see a dog split itself into two identical copies, when he walks trough a door (and one of the dogs always stays outside ...). On the other hand, when I give someone my phone number (a value/primitive type) and he write it down, he only has a copy of it, not the number itself. Its not useful to compare the behavior of primitive types and objects with each other.

Comment: @stereofrog: *Why?* is the right question. To better say why, the OP should share a bit more about what's unintuitive for him. Otherwise it's hard to answer. Next to that, as far as the language is concerned, it could be differed  between assignment and copy (on write). That might open the eyes on how the language work and foster the understanding to use the language as a tool rather than throwing expectations against it.

Answer (score 9):

**object copy vs object clone**

```
class test{
public $name;
public $addr;
}
// i create a object $ob
$ob=new test();

// object copy 

$ob2=$ob;

// in object copy both object will represent same memory address 
// example 
$ob->name='pankaj raghuwanshi';

// i am printing second object
echo $ob2->name;
// output is : pankaj raghuwanshi

// another example 

$ob2->name='raghuwanshi pankaj';
echo $ob->name;
// output is :  raghuwanshi pankaj

// it means in copy of object original and copy object share same memory place
```

**now clone of an object**

```
$ob1=clone $ob;

echo $ob1->name;  // output is :  raghuwanshi pankaj
echo $ob->name;   // output is :  raghuwanshi pankaj

 $ob1->name='PHP Clone';
 $ob->name='PHP Obj';

echo $ob1->name;  // output is :  PHP Clone
echo $ob->name;   // output is :  PHP Obj

// on the base of these output we can say both object have their own memory space 
// both are independent
```

Comment: this answer is proper with live example

Answer (score 4):

Objects in php5 are essentially pointers, that is, an object variable contains only an address of the object data located somewhere else. An assignment `$obj1 = $obj2` only copies this address and doesn't touch the data itself. This may indeed appear counterintuitive, but in fact it's quite practical, because you only rarely need to have two copies of the object. I wish php arrays used the same semantics.

Comment: Some functions only accepts native arrays of course. `$result = new ArrayObject(array_map($cb, $arrOb->getArrayCopy()));`