# Is it possible to replace an object but keep all the same references to it

Tags: php

Is possible in PHP to replace an object A of class1 with an object B of class2 so that all references to A are now redirected to B.

The goal is to avoid tracking all the references to A, which may exist in a complex system of relations, and replacing the object one by one.

A bit more context: I need object A to be a temporary stand-in during parsing of an svg file, representing a `<use>` tag, to be replaced by the actual instance referred to by the `<use>` tag, once the file is parsed. The problem is that `<use>` may refer to a tag that has not been parsed yet, and `<use>` tag may refer to object of different geometric type.

Here is a (generic) example of the behavior I want:

```
$A = new Class1();

$Array_1["name1"] = $A;
...
$Array_n["namen"] = $A;
$object_1->field_1 = $A;
...
$object_n->field_n = $A;

$B = new Class2(); // In my case, $B is assigned to a field of $A, and both extend the same abstract class.

TELL_PHP_ENGINE_TO_REPLACE($A, $B);  //Needed operation
```

Note that this operation must happen at the level of the php engine, by changing the the handle and handler fields, handler table, (etc.) related to the zval structure.

This may be impossible currently, but I want to check before I invest time writing a function to do all replacements manually. Also, a manual function will have to be updated every time I modify the architecture.

Comment: Not sure i understood evreyhting but as PHP 5 object are passed by reference so $obj_a=$obj_b would make a reference copy of a. This might  be intersting for you => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972860/object-copy-versus-clone-in-php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php «When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables will remain references. »

Comment: Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK, here is an example:

Comment: As you want, there's no way. But you can use the Proxy Pattern to make an A object wrap another B object (which is not created yet), Then, create the object when it's needed. There are three types of proxies, the one used by doctrine can do the work as well. If I'm not wrong (I can't see the video right now), the link below contains a short explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka8wlV8M6Vg

Comment: Another examples: http://ocramius.github.io/presentations/proxy-pattern-in-php/

Comment: Thanks! Using a proxy object may be too complicated for the particular problem I want to solve. However, I was planning to use a proxy object at a later stage, to implement lazy loading. Nothing stops me from using the proxy to solve both problems. Maybe, I should move this implementation as a higher priority task.